# 'mapping fragments' error trying to add table in database via 'Update Model From Database' with VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I added a new table ATTACHMENTS_UNSUBMITTED in my Oracle database with a constraint 'FK_REQ_ID' Foreign Key constraint to an existing table.column REQUESTS.REQUEST_ID.

The new table ATTACHMENTS_UNSUBMITTED also has a Primary Key constraint for the same column as Foreign Key: ATTACHMENTS_UNSUBMITTED.REQUEST_ID.  The tables and foreign keys are tested in Oracle as working with SQL.  When I go to my edmx diagram and right click 'Update Model From Database' in VS2017 and check the new table 'Add', I get the error:

> Error 3013: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1461:Missing
>   table mapping: Foreign key constraint 'FK_REQ_ID' from table
>   ATTACHMENTS_UNSUBMITTED (REQUEST_ID) to table REQUESTS (REQUEST_ID):
>   no mapping specified for the table
>   ATTACHMENTS_UNSUBMITTED.  PublicationClearanceWorkflow    C:\gitRepo\MCW_dev\PublicationClearanceWorkflow\Models\PCW.edmx 1462

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1, MVC 5.2.3.

Comment: I found my error:  Table ATTACHMENTS_UNSUBMTTED was created in Oracle without a defined column size for the Foreign Key REQUEST_ID.  Once I recreated the table with every column having a defined size, the table was able included in the Entity Framework via 'Update Model from Database.'

Comment: The other thing to check is the precision of the oracle NUMBER field - in my case one side of the relation was NUMBER and the other was NUMBER(9,0) - in this case adding the table into Entity fails